# [comp setWeekday:(indexPath.row +2)]; is resetting last cell in section to row 0

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am putting dates of the year in to a uitableview (grouped style ) with each section being one week. Having 7 cells, 1 for each corresponding day of the week. I am adding 2 to indexpath.row because I want the week to start on Monday. And cells are 0 based. The issue I am having is that it works all except for the last cell on each section is being treated as indexPath.row 0. Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because the last weekday value is set to 8 (row 6 + 2 = 8), whereas the Gregorian  Calendar only allows values up until 7.

From the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Weekday units are the numbers 1 through n, where n is the number of days in the week. For example, in the Gregorian calendar, n is 7 and Sunday is represented by 1.

Comment: Thanks that helped out a lot. I solved it by using an if statement for the last cell and set the week to the next week and set the day to 1